# Urban Airship posting data

Tags: urbanairship.com

How should i post data to urban airship so it works correctly? I've tried this, but get error that i havent posted any data

```
<form enctype="application/json" method="POST" action="https://go.urbanairship.com/api/push/broadcast/">
<input type="hidden" name="username" value="my_app_key"/>
<input type="hidden" name="password" value="my_master_secret"/>
<input type="hidden" name="data" value='{
        "aps": {
                 "badge": 15,
                 "alert": "Hello from Urban Airship!",
                 "sound": "cat.caf"
        },
        "exclude_tokens": [
        ]
}'/>
<button type="submit"/>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Browsers generally only support enctype "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" and "multipart/form-data".  What's probably happening here is the form is not posting valid JSON, but instead url-encoded data where on of the keys is 'data' and the value is the long string of JSON.

Your best bet would be to call a javascript function when you press the submit button which posts the data with proper content-type and formatting.  Using something like JQuery.post() http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/ would be pretty helpful.

Comment: Thank you for your response! Do you have any experience with UrbanAirship? Gonna try it out with jQuery :)

Comment: @AntonGildebrand I happen to be one of the founders ;-)

Comment: Then i assume you have some experience with UA ;)